# Accessing the information stored in a value tag of an html element

Tags: jquery, html

Hello there I'm working on a project and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the logic that would allow me to access the `value` tag I put in a `<li>` element. I want to be able to access the value of `value` to pass that in as an a value to change the background of a div somewhere down the page using jQuery. I've tried rooting around in the console and checked out similar questions here on StackOverflow. I tried using the attribute equals selector `$("#colors li")[1][value="blue"]` like so and *undefined* is returned in the console.

Here's what I have:

```
<ul id="colors">
  <li value="blue"></li>
  <li value="yellow"></li>
  <li value="violet"></li>
<ul>
```

I want to take those "blue", "yellow" or "violet" strings and pass them into a function that looks like this, into the double brackets so I can change the background of a div on a whim using a drop down menu:

```
$select.change(function(){
   $("#preview").css("background" , [[ call the value here ]]);
}
```

Comment: Which `li` value would you retrieve in your example - how does it relate to the `$select`?

Comment: $select is a drop down menu I have added using JQuery. I would like to access all of them because those colors become identifiers for PDFs in the future.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, how can you set a background to multiple colours?

Comment: Access them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#colors li').click(function(e) {
    $("#preview").css("background", this.getAttribute('value'));
    // in jQuery this.getAttribute('value')  --> $(this).attr('value')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="preview" style="height: 30px;width: 30px;">

</div>
<ul id="colors">
    <li value="blue">blue</li>
    <li value="yellow">yellow</li>
    <li value="violet">violet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's nearly what I'd like to happen, but ideally I'd like to access the string attached to each individual value.

Comment: @m00saca  If you refer to the string contained into the attribute value I updated the snippet

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't really think that I asked the right question, but this was helpful in and of itself.